# как отобразить один элемент из текстового файла?

Tags: c++

У меня например если числа: 51 66 4 10 100

Мне нужен только 51.
Как мне это сделать?

Comment: это всегда будет именно первый ?

Comment: Да, желательно первый элемент.

Comment: `ifstream st;int in;st >> in;`

Comment: Большое Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Для этого можно использовать `ifstream`

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::ifstream fin("name.ext");
    char buff[128];
    fin >> buff;
    std::cout << buff << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

По-хорошему стоит добавить проверку на успешное открытие и чтение.